# Raven Db Join on simple List

Tags: ravendb

I have this kind of structure stored in Raven DB

```
public class AAA
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class BBB
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<int> AAAIds { get; set; } 
}
```

and I'm trying to get a query to basically show something like:

```
public class AAA_BBB
{
   public int AAB_Id { get; set; }
   public string AAA_Name { get; set; }
   public bool ContainsAtLeastOneBBB { get; set; }
 }
```

I'm trying to do something like:
var AAA_BBB = session.Query().Include(a=>a.AAAIds.Select(a=>a))

Answer (score 0):

You need something like:

```
session.Query<BBB>().Include<BBB,AAA>(x=>x.AAAIds)
```